# Calling multiple functions which have multiple variables with one button. Self argument doesn't get recognized

Tags: python, class, tkinter, button, command

I have to execute several functions with one button click. The functions have multiple variables. I think I'm pretty close to get it working but when I click the button the error `TypeError: all_functions.function_1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` occurs.

But when I add `self` in this manner: `all_functions.function_1(self)` I reveive another error which says `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`. I wonder why `all_functions.function_1` gets recognized perfectly fine while `self` does not.

```
import tkinter as tk

class all_functions():

    def function_1(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        print(self.a, self.b)

    def function_2(self):
        self.c = 3
        self.d = 4
        print(self.c, self.d)

root = tk.Tk()

create_button = tk.Button(root, command=lambda:[all_functions.function_1(), all_functions.function_2()], text="Button")

create_button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not instantiating an object of the class.
Use

```
create_button = tk.Button(root, command=lambda:[all_functions().function_1(), all_functions().function_2()], text="Button")
```

instead of

```
create_button = tk.Button(root, command=lambda:[all_functions.function_1(), all_functions.function_2()], text="Button")
```

Comment: Please note that this will create a separate class instance for each function call. If the functions intend to share data within an instance, it won't work unless you use a shared instance.

Comment: @Steven yes, you are right. I assume OP is a beginner so I thought that the approach which I wrote would be clearer for him to understand if he is still learning the basics of OOPs :).

Comment: @Steven Yes, I'm fairly new to python. How does this shared instance work?

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/class would be a good resource to start. If you are totally new to OOP, look at https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/object-oriented-programming.

Comment: Thanks for the sources @chess_madridista. I think I really have to work myself through this first because the answers from you and Steven don't work with my real code, probably because of this shared instance stuff.

Comment: Welcome sir :D! The error could also be because of incorrect use of tkinter. What is the console displaying?

Comment: It says `TypeError: all_functions.__init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd'`.  I used __init__ so the variables are recognized between the functions but I receive this error like before with `self` in the code line of the button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247952/discussion-between-plantz-and-chess-madridista).

Answer (score 4):

You need to instantiate the class first:

```py
af = all_functions() # ← Create instance, which activates self
create_button = tk.Button(root, command=lambda:[af.function_1(), af.function_2()], text="Button")
```

If this isn't just a made-up example, there is probably no need for a class at all, because none of the functions are sharing any data.

Comment: You're right. In this example the class is not necessary but as you indicate it would be necessary if the functions share data. And that's what they should do in the real code. But for this problem I kept the code small to obtain a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Plantz did this not work for you? I saw you mentioned you're still having trouble. Are you getting a different error?

Comment: In the end I figured it out to get this to work with my real code but I had to do some other things, too. But thanks for checking even after this time!